# I am trying to obtain modules that a process running on a remote computer has loaded

Tags: powershell, process, remote-access

how to obtain modules that a process running on a remote computer has loaded using PowerShell.

There are some process modules that I am getting error for, like permission denied and cannot enumerate. How can i address these error.

> Cannot enumerate the modules of the **"services"** process.+
>   CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (System.Diagnostics.Process
>   (services):Process) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException+
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   CouldnotEnumerateModules,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comands.GetProcessCommand
>   + PSComputerName

**using command:**

```
$Module = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Get-Process -Module }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't specific to remoting: **there are processes whose modules fundamentally<sup>[1]</sup> cannot be enumerated due to lack of permissions, even when running with elevation (as admin)**.

Since the errors report are *non-terminating* errors, you can **simply *ignore* the (all) errors with `-ErrorAction Ignore`** at the source:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Get-Process -Module -ErrorAction Ignore }
```

**If you want to capture the error messages, so you can determine the processes for which enumeration failed, use `-ErrorVariable errs -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`**, which silences the errors, but collects them in variable `$errs` for later inspection:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Get-Process -Module } -ErrorVariable errs -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Specifically, **`$errs.TargetObject`** will list the process objects whose modules couldn't be enumerated.

---

If the intent is to **find (and possibly kill) all processes that use a module (DLL) of interest**, use the standard [`tasklist.exe` utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist) or [`taskkill.exe` utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill) with the `/m` parameter.

```
$moduleOfInterest = 'oleaut32.dll' # example DLL
$pids = (tasklist /m $moduleOfInterest /fo csv | ConvertFrom-Csv).PID

# Alternatively, use `taskkill` in lieu of `tasklist` above in 
# order to kill the processes directly.
if ($pids) { Stop-Process -Id $pids -WhatIf }
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`, once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

However, with this approach you may run into permission issues as well.

Note that `tasklist.exe` and `taskkill.exe` have a built-in remoting feature via parameter `/S`, allowing a single remote machine to be targeted.

However, using PowerShell's general-purpose remoting (via `Invoke-Command`s  `-ComputerName` / `-Session` parameters) gives you more flexibility, notably the ability to target *multiple* computers in parallel.

---

<sup>[1] At least by default, elevation alone isn't enough; if anyone knows if there's a way to enumerate nonetheless, do let us know.  [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60727948/45375) asks for that information specifically.</sup>