# Powershell : Get-Process does not enumerate all process modules

Tags: powershell, process, enumerate

There are some process modules that I am getting error for, like *permission denied* and *cannot enumerate* for processes like Services, Idle, csrss. It appears there are processes whose modules fundamentally cannot be enumerated due to lack of permissions, even when running with elevation (as admin). **How and what permission need to be obtained to be able to enumerate these processes.**

Cmdlet executed: `Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Get-Process -Module }` and for local just  `Get-Process -Module`

Excerpts of Errors Encountered:

> Cannot enumerate the modules of the "services" process.+ CategoryInfo : **PermissionDenied**: (System.Diagnostics.Process (services):Process) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : **CouldnotEnumerateModules**,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comands.GetProcessCommand + PSComputerName
>
> Select-Object : **Exception getting "Modules": "Access is denied"**
>
> t-Process | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Modules -outvariable proces .  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (System.Diagnostics.Process (csrss):PSObject) [Select-Object], GetValueInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyEvaluationExpand,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

Comment: Any suggestions...